# How can I get the associated Id of a View as a string?

Tags: android, view, findviewbyid

When you create a layout, you define an id for your views like this:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/myImage"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/main01" />
```

and in your code you have:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
```

now you have the object of `img`.

How can I get the id of `img` ("myImage") **as a string**? I need something like this:

```
String strId = getStringId(img);
// now strId is "myImage"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Log.i("============ Id","::"+getResources().getResourceEntryName(img.getId()));
```

**Output : ============ Id :: myImage**

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
String value = getResources().getString(R.id.myImage);
```

Comment: no i need a function that gets the View and returns the string value of its id